# Finding exact string in a file using a variable (grep)

Tags: bash, grep

I am writing a script currently that is searching inside a txt file.

So basically I have a loop that grabs a name from a txt file and then searches for that name in another file (file2), but I am having issues.

```
name=flex

grep $name file2 > file2output
```

So if file2 (file I am searching inside of)
has something like

```
    1 flex-inside

    2 flex

    1 flex-end
```

It will match all three of those when I only want it to match the exact string flex.

I want it to only match

```
2 flex
```

I was trying to do something where it would look for whatever is in $name and then \n. But nothing is working.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: `grep -Fx "$name" file`

Comment: @anubhava just tried that. No luck.

Comment: Now try `grep -Fw "$name" file`.  And, don't just say "no luck."  That's useless.  Tell us exactly what happened: Was there an error?  If so, show us the complete error message.  Was there too much or too little output?  If so, what exactly what was the output?

Comment: No line output at all. Completely blank file.

Just tried `grep "$name$"` and it worked perfectly.

I also just tried `grep -Fw "$name"` and it still finds all instances of flex. 

Thank you for the help though. :)

Comment: If `grep -Fw "$name"` produces output but `grep -Fx "$name" file` does not, that means that you have characters, invisible or otherwise, before or after `flex` in that line.  If `grep "$name$" file` works for you, that means that those characters, visible or not, are _before_ `flex`.  Try running `hexdump -C file` and see what extra characters are on the `flex` line.

Comment: Completely my fault for not giving correct data. I have fixed the question regardless. The file I am looking through is sorted then I use uniq -c on the same file which gives it a count etc. This is all before I try to grep it. 

So the data is actually a bit different. Like I said, I changed the question above so that my solution fits what I am asking.

Comment: It sounds like the word you are looking for will always appear at the end of the line.  In that case, try `grep " $name$" file` where there is a space before `$name` and, the final `$` is the regex symbol for end-of-the-line.

Comment: `grep "$name$" file` ended up working :)

Comment: No, that won't work.  You wanted only whole word matches.  Without the space in the regex, it will match `aflex` or `bflex` as well `flex`

Comment: Ah! okay well, thank you for correcting me. You are right. Sorry, I am new to all this, just started learning about a week ago. You should put your solution as the answer! Thank you so much for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, the input file looks like:

```
$ cat file2
    1 flex-inside
    3 reflex
    2 flex
    1 flex-end
```

We want to select the line matching `flex` but not `reflex` or `flex-end`, etc.  In that case, try:

```
$ name='flex'
$ grep " $name$" file2
    2 flex
```

There are two key points here:

1. There is a space before `$name` to assure that words like `reflex` are not matched.
2. There is a dollar sign, `$`, after `$name` to require that `flex` occurs at the end of the line.

#### Extended version: handling embedded spaces

The above all assumes that the matched text after the numbers does not include spaces.  Consider for example the input file:

```
$ cat file2
    1 flex inside
    3 re flex
    2 flex
    1 flexible
```

We can select the one line matching `flex` with:

```
$ grep -E "^[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+$name$" file2
    2 flex
```

Here, `^[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+` matches zero or more  spaces that begin the line followed by digits followed by one or more spaces.  This is followed by `$name$` which matches `$name` appearing at the end (`$`) of the line.

The use of character classes like `[:space:]` and `[:digit:]` assures that this code is unicode safe.

Comment: Thank you so much. Great explanation.